# MySQL order by after complex results

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have these results in respons MySQL statement:

```
1   |    1
2   |    1.1
3   |    1.1.1
4   |    2
5   |    2.1
6   |    2.1.1
```

I need to sort them the way that major digits are in `DESC` order and sub-results are in `ASC` order:

```
1   |    2
2   |    2.1
3   |    2.1.1
2   |    1
5   |    1.1
6   |    1.1.1
```

Is there any `IF` conditions within `ORDER BY` ?

Here's the query I used to sort the comments in 3 level hierarchy:

```
SELECT *, message_id AS SORT_KEY
FROM forum_comment a
WHERE replyToMsg = 0

UNION ALL
SELECT a.*, CONCAT(b.message_id, '.', a.message_id) AS SORT_KEY
FROM forum_comment a, 
     forum_comment b
WHERE b.replyToMsg = 0
      and b.message_id = a.replyToMsg

UNION ALL
SELECT a.*, CONCAT(c.message_id,'.', b.message_id,'.', a.message_id) AS SORT_KEY
FROM forum_comment a,
     forum_comment b,
     forum_comment c
WHERE c.replyToMsg = 0
  and b.message_id = a.replyToMsg
  and c.message_id = b.replyToMsg

ORDER BY SORT_KEY
```

Comment: Please add your query you have tried

Comment: I've added the full query.

Comment: are you expecting 1.1.2 to come before 1.1.10?

Comment: 1.1.2 will be after 1.1.1 but definitely before 1.1.10. Any sub-comments are in `ASC` order.

Answer (score 1):

```
select bar
from foo
order by
    substring_index(bar,'.',1)+0 desc,
    length(bar)-length(replace(bar,'.',''))>0,
    substring_index(substring_index(bar,'.',2),'.',-1)+0,
    length(bar)-length(replace(bar,'.',''))>1,
    substring_index(substring_index(bar,'.',3),'.',-1)+0;
```

Comment: wasn't quite right, updated

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you so much. By the way, I managed to catch your first (unmodified) answer and the second one and it produced the same results. I'm not sure of the difference (if you can explain, I'll appreciate it) ... but it worked!!!

Comment: @ekashking I think 1.2 would sort as if it were 1.2.2 if you don't check how many . there are before trying to get the third component.  It was something like that